# Default Options not working in user-defined function for SymbolName

Tags: function-construction, options, symbols, assignment, optional-arguments

**Abstract** I have a function `objectName[symbol]` that returns the `SymbolName` as both a standalone function or when nested inside other functions. I have another function in which I would like it to return a Row[...] with `objectName[symbol]` and value `Evaluate[symbol]` but I would also like it to have an override option where an alternate name could be returned instead of the default `SymbolName`. Problem is it won't work when set as an `Options`. What am I missing?

`About the Code` For `abc = 123` the code should output `{abc -> 123}` however when given an alternate name it correctly outputs `{Row[{"alternatename", " \[Rule] ", 123}, " "]}`

```
objectName = Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], {HoldFirst}];
Options[rowNameValue] = {name -> objectName[symbol]};
rowNameValue[symbol_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{name, id, value, fn},
   value = Evaluate[symbol];
   id = OptionValue[name];
   id = If[MatrixQ[value] || VectorQ[value], Style[id, Bold], id, id];
   fn = If[MatrixQ[value] || VectorQ[value], MatrixForm, 
     TraditionalForm, StandardForm];
   {Row[{id, " \[Rule] ", Apply[fn, value]}, " "]
    }
   ];
abc = 123
objectName[abc]
rowNameValue[abc]
rowNameValue[abc, name -> "alternatename"]
```

Comment: From a quick glance, the problem lies in the fact that `objectName[symbol]` in your `Options` is immediately evaluated (to `symbol`) so `objectName` is never called from within your function; you can check by evaluating `Options[rowNameValue]` after running your definitions. I don't have a simple fix for that off the top of my head; it may be tricky to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some missunderstandings in how Mathematica evaluates expressions. First of all, if you want to access the symbol and not its value only, the function `rowNameValue` needs to have a hold-attribute. Then, the RHS of the `Options` definition will - as MarcoB explained - be evaluated at the time you define it. You could define it with `RuleDelayed` to only evaluate at the time it is used, as you can see from this example:

```
Options[f] = {"Time" :> DateString[]};
f[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue["Time"]
```

Unfortunately that will not help in your situation because there is no way to pass the argument `symbol` to that option-definition. So what you have to do to achieve what you want is to explicitly code that case. The following code is how I would approach your problem:

```
objectName = Function[Null,SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]],{HoldFirst}];

ClearAll[rowNameValue];
SetAttributes[rowNameValue, HoldFirst];
Options[rowNameValue] = {name -> Automatic};
rowNameValue[symbol_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
    id=Replace[OptionValue[name],Automatic:>objectName[symbol]],
    value=symbol
  },
  If[MatrixQ[value] || VectorQ[value],
    id = Style[id, Bold];
    value = MatrixForm[value];
  ];
  {Row[{id, " \[Rule] ", value}, " "]}
]
```

There would be other ways to achieve what you want, but it is a widely used convention to set an option-value to `Automatic` when the default can be computed from the arguments to the function.

Some additional notes: I made the following changes which have nothing to do with you actual question but think are worth knowing:

- I would suggest to use `Module` as the default scoping construct and only use `Block` when you really need it. You will find several QAs on this site which explain the differences and use cases of the two.
- There is no reason to use the forth argument of `If` in this case: by convention the internal Mathematica functions ending with `Q` will always return either `True` or `False` in Mathematica, so in this case the forth argument will never be executed.
- I changed the logic of the `If` statement in a way that I find easier to read.
- I guess you are aware of the fact that the `Row` construct will only be good for displaying purposes and is likely to cause problems if you try to use it in further computations, especially it of course can not be used as a replacement rule...

Comment: thank you i understand it better now and i yes with slight modifications for making function more universal i did use your solution. :)

Comment: @JulesManson: great to hear this was of help. thanks for the accept...